# how to check if the a button has been pressed (in a jsp file)

Tags: jsp, input, request, hide, getparameter

I am working on a JSP file(don't want to use a servlet), I have a simple form, 2 labels, 2 inputs and 2 buttons, and I want to print out the submitted string **on the same jsp page** , the problem is that the last values submitted remain printed on the screen as I try new ones, that is why I thought of a test to check whether the button submit was clicked before we move to the display, I tried this code :

```
       <body>
       <form  method='post'>
       <pre>
       <label>Username</label> <input type="text" name="user"  required/>
       <label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="pwd" required />
       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="confirm" name ="submit" /> 
       <input type="reset" value="clear"  /> 
       </pre>
       </form>
       <br>
       // test if the submit button was clicked (check if value of submit is confirm)

        <% String x=request.getParameter("submit")%>
        <% if (x.equals("confirm")){ %>

       <% if (request.getParameter("user")!="" && request.getParameter("pwd")!=""){ %>
       <center>
       <h4> user is : <% out.write(request.getParameter("user")); %> </h4>
       <br> 
       <h4> password is : <% out.write(request.getParameter("pwd")); %> </h4>
       </center>
       <% } else {  %>

        <h4> inputs r empty !! </h4> 

       <% } %>
       <% } %>
       </body>
```

I get an error at line :

```
       <% if (x.equals("confirm")){ %>
```

any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, stop opening and closing JSP tags unnecessarily. Its sloppy and unreadable.  Secondly, you're missing a semi-colon.  Third, you need to check for the possibility that the parameter is null. When the form was not submitted, the parameter is null.

This is bad:

```
 <% String x=request.getParameter("submit")%>
 <% if (x.equals("confirm")){ %>
```

Do it like this:

```
 <%
   String x = request.getParameter("submit");
   if(x!=null && x.equals("confirm"))
   {
     ...
```

You could also reverse the string comparison.  If you use a dot operator on a variable that is null, you get a null pointer exception.  So you could use the dot operator on the string literal, and thus avoid explicitly checking for null:

```
 <%
   String x = request.getParameter("submit");
   if("confirm".equals(x))
   {
     ...
```

Also once you fix this, you will run into a problem with `if (request.getParameter("user")!=""`.  You need to use `.equals()` because in Java for String `==`, `!=` do not compare string contents, but compare pointer (i.e. memory address) equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems not too much old . So I can safely add an answer to this question .

Basically when you want to process submitted form data in same page , you cab use the following code snippet :

```
    <%
    String check_submit_form = request.getParameter("submit");
    if((request.getParameter("btnLogon") == null)?false:true){
            for(int i =0;i<=100;i++){
                 out.println("Congrts Bro . you have done a great job .");
            }
    }
    else{
    %>

   <form name="form_logon" method="POST" action ="logonHome.jsp">
     <input type="submit" value="Click for Finger Verification" name="btnLogon">
  </form>
  <%
   }
  %>
```

The code is self-explanatory . If you hit the submit button , then you can process the form otherwise you will be redirected to the form . Hope this helps .